# Appending Attribute Table of multiple feature class with same points/ pointID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, attribute-table, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7

I used extract by points function to extract values from multiple rasters using a point feature class. The output is a couple hundred point feature classes with values associated with those rasters.

I would like to append all the attributes table of feature class (they all have same POINTID) so that I have all the information I want in a single table.

How do I do this?

See attached screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I would like to append RASTERVALU of each feature class (SRAD_KRIGXXXXX) to "FOOTPRINT" attribute table (maintaining its file naming structure).

Such that the FootPrint feature class will have field names SRAD_KRIG2007001, SRAD_KRIG2007002, SRAD_KRIG2007003, etc. with values from their RASTERVALU field.

I was wondering if python scripting is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an empty table for output and then iterate over your featureclasses, joining and transferring information from feature classes to your output table as you go.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\wherever your data is'

# create an empty dbf file using a template
arcpy.CreateTable_management("C:/Data/..","SRad_KrigAll.dbf","Template.dbf", "") 

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('SRad_Krig*')
tblOut = 'SRad_KrigAll.dbf'

fcFirst = fcList[0]

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fcList[0], 'tv')
arcpy.TableToDBASE_conversion('tv', tblOut)
arcpy.DeleteField_management(tblOut, 'RASTERVALUE')

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(tblOut, 'tvOut')

for fc in fcList:
    field = 'k' + fcFirst.replace('SRad_Krig', '')
    arcpy.AddField_management(tblOut, field, 'DOUBLE')
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc, 'tv')
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(tblOut, 'OBJECTID', 'tv', 'OBJECTID')
    arcpy.CalculateField_management('tvOut', tblOut + '.' + field, \
    '[' + fc + '.RASTERVALU]')
    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management('tvOut', fc)
```

Comment: The python code gave output as "TV.dbf" with values from first featureclass. 

ERROR from Python:

Converted tv to C:\Data\SRad_KrigALL.dbf\tv successfully.
Unable to Process
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000310: The Field name must not start with a number
Failed to execute (AddField).

Comment: hmmm...expected `tblOut = 'SRad_KrigAll.dbf'`. Not sure how it ended up with `TV.dbf`. Seems my `TableToDBASE` bit can be dumped if you would rather go w/`CreatTable` (one should go, tho--redundant). Also, pre-pended a string to the field name based on ERROR 000310.

Comment: Process finished with exit code 1.

IndexError: list index out of range. 

Traceback: 
fcFirst = fcList[0]

Comment: Sorry, that should be `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('SRad_Krig*')` with an asterisk. I'll mod the code.

Comment: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Output Folder: Dataset C:/Test/SRad_KrigAll.dbf does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (TableToDBASE).

Is there something wrong with the template I created? How am I supposed to create the template for this? Also, could you please comment on what each syntax is doing for clarity. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The template is not my idea. If someone else added it, perhaps they can explain. I do not use it. I think this part could be skipped and still work (i.e., I'm thinking the original form of my suggestion would work).

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, it would be using the [Summarize Data in a Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000055000000) function on the resulting attribute table of points.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was looking. I will post screen shots so my question becomes more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds a little messy, but have you tried joining two tables to start, then exporting the table with the join (so that the join is saved). Then you can repeat and join that table to the 3rd table, and so on.

Comment: Yes, that is best when we have few joins to make. My situation is different, requiring hundreds of attribute tables to be merged at once.